# Method to duplicate data from a Solr server

Tags: collections, solr, duplicates

I run Solr-7.4.0 which I have installed onto a VM running Ubuntu 16.04. I have a PC running Windows 10.

I have been tasked with analyzing data from a number of different Solr collections that connect into another system.

Suppose these Solr collections have the following addresses:

1) http://localhost1:8983
2) http://localhost2:7475
3) http://localhost3:4029

Each collection above is hosted on a different, physical server. I have no control over these servers or the data inside them.

My query is as follows:

Is it possible for me to duplicate these Solr collections (scheme, index and all) into my PC or VM?
If yes, how is it done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can replicate them easily in your PC/VM. The steps should be like these-

1. First copy the configsets to your local PC. You can copy the configsets in many different ways. If they are running in cloud mode you can download them using 'downconfig' from the source machines then upload them to your PC using 'upconfig' command. In standalone mode you can just copy the files.
2. Then you should create the core(collection) using that config set uploaded/copied in step1.
3. Copy the data. You can go to the "Dataimport" tab of SolrAdmin of the destination PC and import the data from source solr server. In this case you will have to put the source solr server address in the file 'solr-data-config.xml' of the destination solr server.

Comment: Thank you Sharif. I am aware that these Solr collections are running in cloud mode. However, I am at a loss as to how I should use downconfig, as I do not know the zkHost of any of these servers. Is there a way to find these out? Alternatively, are there other methods to copy the configsets for these collections?

Comment: If you can browse the solr in browser, in the Dashboard tab you'll find something like  "-DzkHost=10.11.31.250:2181,10.11.31.251:2181". Here these are the ip address of zkHost.
You can also browse the cofingsets in browser, go to a collection then click the tab 'Files'. Then you'll se there is a file 'managed-schema'. If you click on it you'll fine the configset in it. It's a large file you'll have to find out the list of fields for your configset carefully.

Comment: I have looked at the Solr Admin UI. I found the DzkHost for the particular collection I am interested in to be DzkHost=hmaster:2181/solr6 As you have mentioned the managed-schema, I found it in the files tab of the collection, and below it in the lost of files is a file named solrconfig.xml. Is this the file I need? If so, how should I extract it into my PC?

Comment: 'managed-schema' is the file where your field list(schema) available. In 'solr.config'  file all the solr environment related configurations are available. You can copy only 'managed-schema' file if you are using default solr configurations. However, you can copy the 'solr.config'  file as well if you have any custom configuration.

Into your pc you can create newcollection with default configurations then replace the files(you can use downconfig & upconfig zk commands)